# Check last element in array matches a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an array of numbers in my mongodb documents and need to check if the last number in that array meets my conditions.

My documents are stored like this:

```
  {
    name: String,
    data: {
      dates: Array,
      numbers: Array
    }
  }
```

and I need to check if the last number in `numbers` "lies between" two other numbers.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the most effficient way you have of doing this is using the JavaScript evaluation of [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) as you can simply find the value of the last array element and test it programatically.

With sample documents:

```js
{ "a": [1,2,3] },
{ "a": [1,2,4] },
{ "a": [1,2,5] }
```

And to query:

```js
db.collection.find(function() { var a = this.a.pop(); return ( a > 2 ) & ( a < 5 ) })
```

Or simply presented with `$where` as a string for evaluation:

```js
Model.find(
    { 
        "$where": "var a = this.a.pop(); return ( a > 2 ) && ( a < 5 )"
    },
    function(err,results) {
        // handling here
    }
);
```

Which is a really simple way to do this and does not have "overhead" such as [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in the aggregation framework created to to "denormalize" and process arrays. Not really efficient there.

In the "future" however, it **will** be. As is currently available in development releases, there is a **`$slice`** operator for the aggregation framework. This operator will allow easy access to the "last" array element for testing.

Since the aggregation framework operators are in "native code" aand not JavaScript to be interpreted, then a single pipeline stage then becomes more efficient than the JavaScript form. Though this listing to do this looks longer in submission:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$anyElementTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": { "$slice": ["$a",-1] },
            "as": "el",
            "in":{
              "$and": [
                { "$gt": [ "$$el", 2 ] },
                { "$lt": [ "$$el", 5 ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

The [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator that already exists is used to "logically filter" with a comparison expression here. Based on the `true/false` match conditions it either "keeps" or "prunes" the document from the results repectively.

The `$slice` operator itself in it's aggregagtion framework form will still untimately return an array, albeit a single element array in this case. This is why [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) is used to "transform" each element into a `true/false` condition and the [**`$anyElementTrue`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) operator reduces the "array" to a singular reponse as is repected by [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/).

So when that is released, then it will be be most efficient way to do this. But until then, stick with the JavaScript as it is presently the fastest way to to this evaluation.

Both query forms return just the first two documents of the sample here:

```js
{ "a": [1,2,3] },
{ "a": [1,2,4] }
```

Comment: Would the equivalent for my example be "this.data.numbers.pop()"?

Comment: @martin Sorry, yes it would. Since it is just a nested object and not an array itself then that is fine. Make sure your structure is consistent though, otherwise that changes the response dramatically.

Comment: If you could show how to use this query with Mongoose, that would've been perfect, I've been trying to implement it but it only returns a circular structure.

Comment: @martin There is no difference. There is no mongoose query structure, only MongoDB. The `$where` operator is a JavaScript condition represented as a string that is sent to the server. Example added anyway.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) may be a feasible way. Assuming name field in your document is unique.

If you have the sample document.

```
   {
     name: "allen",
     data: {
      dates: ["2015-08-08"],
      numbers: [20, 21, 22, 23]
     }
   }
```

The following code is used to do the check. As the **db.collection.aggregate() method returns a cursor** and then we can use cursor's  [`hasNext`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hasNext/) to decide whether the last number lies between the given two numbers.

```
var result = db.last_one.aggregate(
 [
   {
      // deconstruct the array field numbers
      $unwind: "$data.numbers"
   },
   { 
     $group: { 
      _id: "$name", 
      // lastNumber is 23 in this case 
      lastNumber: { $last: "$data.numbers" }
     } 
   },
   {
    $match: {
       lastNumber: { $gt: num1, $lt: num2 }
    }
   }
 ]  
).hasNext()

if (result) print("matched"); else print("not matched")
```

For example, if num1 is 22, num2 is 24, the result is matched; if num1 is 21, num2 is 22, the result is not matched.

But actually, group on name is not a good idea. It's much better if your document has an unique ObjectId then we can group on that _id.

Comment: How do you use this in combination with the find() statement if I have a mongoose model called Company? Sorry if it's obvious but I've never done advanced queries in mongoDB.

Comment: Hey, you don't have to use find, sorry I am not familiar with mongoose. you may check the post [mongoose-aggregate-and-sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623141/mongoose-aggregate-and-sort) to see how use aggregate with mongoose.