# mongoose sum a value across all documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am looking to count all columns with the name amount in the documents that match my query,

```
 tickets.count({time: {$gte: a}, time: {$lte: tomorrow}}).then(function (numTickets) {
```

How can I get the total result of the document column called amount?

Example, if I do have:

```
{ time: 20, amount: 40}
{ time: 40, amount: 20}
```

it would return the total amount(60)?

Remember that I do need to use `{time: {$gte: a}, time: {$lte: tomorrow}` in the query.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try it with the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) using the [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operators, i.e. something like this

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
    { $match: { time: {$gte: a, $lte: tomorrow} } },
    { $group: { _id: null, amount: { $sum: "$amount" } } }
])
```

for example with test data like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e0ed40828913a99c2ceb46"),
    "time" : 20,
    "amount" : 40
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e0ed40828913a99c2ceb47"),
    "time" : 40,
    "amount" : 20
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e0ed40828913a99c2ceb48"),
    "time" : 50,
    "amount" : 10
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e0ed40828913a99c2ceb49"),
    "time" : 10,
    "amount" : 5
}
```

a pipeline (with dummy time range) like the following

```
db.tickets.aggregate([
    { $match: { time: {$gte: 20, $lte: 40} } },
    { $group: { _id: null, amount: { $sum: "$amount" } } }
])
```

would give you a result like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "amount" : 60
}
```

---

[image: Pipeline in action]

Comment: will that work with mongoose too?

cause 
            tickets.aggregate([{ $match: { time: {$gte: a, $lte: tomorrow} } }, { $group: { _id: null, amount: { $sum: "$amount" } } }]).then(function (test) {
 wont work for me, in the terms its not executing it.

Comment: tickets is my mongoose model yes. Would you take a look on teamviewer? , anyway, i will take a look, and accept your answer :)

Comment: Your callback should have two parameters (for error and result) I guess. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623141/mongoose-aggregate-and-sort) SO question shows how to use aggregate pipeline with mongoose - hope that helps. Otherwise I will try to test it myself tonight

Comment: will continue to get it work. im console.logging inside the result, but its never excecuted.

Comment: @DAXaholic i have amount with two decimals points stored as a string how i can get the sum of all records using mongose...?