# Add sum of order from order collection to user collection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am currently working on a nodejs project and I am using mongodb as my database but I have an issue. I want to make a single call using aggregation that will add the sum of a specific user order to the user collection. But I am not sure how to go about it. Please I need some suggestions/help on how to achieve this. Please see the example of objects below.

User Collection

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "Henry"
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "John"
  }
]
```

Order Collection

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    userId: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    userId: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    userId: 1
  }
]
```

Expected result after making the mongoose call

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "Henry",
    orderCount: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "John",
    orderCount: 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongoose sum a value across all documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588588/mongoose-sum-a-value-across-all-documents)

Answer (score 0):

Query

- group orders by userId and sum the orderCount
- lookup with users to get the user information(here the `name` field)

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b499e)

```js
orders.aggregate(
[{"$group": {"_id": "$userId", "orderCount": {"$sum": 1}}},
  {"$lookup": 
    {"from": "users",
     "localField": "_id",
     "foreignField": "_id",
     "as": "users"}},
  {"$set": {"name": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$users.name", 0]}}},
  {"$unset": ["users"]}])
```

If your users have more fields than just `name` replace the `$set`
with this

```
{"$replaceRoot": 
  {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$$ROOT" , {"$arrayElemAt": ["$users", 0]}]}}}
```