# Mongoose find all posts and get the hottest categories

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have this problem where i need to find the hottest categories from all the posts that i've search.

This is my POST schema model

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    maincategory: String,
    subcategory: String,
    quantity: String,
    budget: Number,
    name: String,
    description: String,
});


PostSchema.index({name: 'text', description: 'text'});
```

So what i need to do is, crawl to all the posts, check their main category and sub category, then after crawling to all posts and get their categories, i need to count on how many posts on this categories then sort out the categories where i will show the categories which has the highest amount of posts. Then i will show which categories are the hottest, maybe top 5

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After searching Stackoverflow for answer, i finally found it! It's called aggregate. (Sorry didn't know the word)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26623244/6802296 Thanks to this link i was able to solve my problem